# S7 slow practically unusable at app layer

Tags: mobile-data, lagging

I know this seems a common complaint but I've been through the forums and can't find any solution to this very specific problem. Symptoms: Since returning from abroad 2 months ago, my S7 is barely receiving data from the mobile network *at the app layer*. e.g. I just tried to load google news and it took about 20 seconds. Next two attempts timed out.

Weird thing is if I enable the hotspot and connect a tablet or laptop, it loads the same page instantly. Therefore antannae is obv. fine, data transfer test from the laptop to the hotspot are as follows:

[image]

However I can't even run that test directly on the phone.
On wifi it behaves much better with no noticeable slowness of data transfer.

What I have tried:

- Uninstalling all games, unnecessary apps my kids had on etc.
- Clearing the cache
- Using a cache cleaning app
- factory reset
- hard reset
- wiping the APN settings and re-pulling
- every permutation of the network's APN settings

none of the above has any effect. I've pretty much taken to bringing my 7" tablet around nowadays and hotspotting instead of using the phone directly.

Can anyone please put me out of my misery - am just on the verge of chucking the thing altogether now..

Comment: Since you traveled, could the phone have changed its Network Mode there to give you a better reception, but failed to undo the change here? Visit Settings > Mobile Networks > Network Mode, and experiment to see if any of them restore functionality.

Comment: hi thanks for your suggestion much appreciated but yes played round with this also. Only setting which works at all really is 4G. Selecting any of the others results in even worse performance and kills the hotspotting altogether